# Monitor not booting up with PC - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: monitor

I've recently made the conversion from windows 7 to ubuntu 14.04 and loving it! 
...Until this morning when I've tried to boot up my computer which seems to be booting fine, but my monitor is remaining black - not even showing bios etc.

From memory it's running an Intel I7 3.4ghz / AMD graphics / 8gb ram

Just unsure as to what I should do or what it could be.. and yes it's plugged in at the back.

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)